# Flutter Firestore make runTransaction instantaneous on device

Tags: dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

Since starting to use the [`DatabaseReference.runTransaction`](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/7e4d7a6befdf696725f1130f6b441fa4b4864c11/packages/cloud_firestore/lib/src/firestore.dart#L107) function, I have a problem with it.

Having watched the latest [Google Developers Flutter promotion video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqJ_KjFzL9I), I now have the confidence to present this problem accurately!

**Using** [`DatabaseReference.updateData`](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/4acdcc1cdd73fd74fdadba452a37e708ae895731/packages/cloud_firestore/lib/src/document_reference.dart#L57) will pass the information instantaneously to the `Stream<QuerySnapshot>`. This can [be seen here](https://youtu.be/DqJ_KjFzL9I?t=9m55s). The moment he taps the item, i.e. `updateData` is updated, the counter is also immediately updated, which is very nice and *expected behavior*. *This means* that the device you execute the update on updates instantly, but the other device has a delay fetching from the server.

The moment you transition to `runTransaction`, this functionality is *completely lost* and you will have to wait for the regular update that is not handled on device, but sent from Firestore. [Looking at the new implementation](https://youtu.be/DqJ_KjFzL9I?t=10m55s), you can clearly see that there is **a delay** and worse than this that *both devices* update at the **same time**. From this one can clearly derive that there is no *on device* data update, which is very annoying for UI.

I am *not searching* for a workaround because I have obviously implemented that myself, which means that I am managing my update on my own, in this case I would update the counter internally the moment I tap on the updater.

What I want to find out is whether or not there is a way to **enable** the **instantaneous** *behavior* with **`runTransaction`**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that is possible, otherwise it wouldn't be a transaction. 
A transaction has to be [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) and therefore needs to be coordinated at a central point - the server.

This is why with a transaction there is no local update that is then synchronized to the server.

Comment: In my memory I could clearly see me having this behavior on Android, but I could be wrong there. Even if not I cannot quite understand objections with having a responsive UI even if it is just handling the transaction like it was executed on the offline copy of the database. Do you reckon that proposing an issue in that case would lead to anything?

Comment: If you can reproduce in native Android, then it's definitely worth a try. "objections with having a responsive UI" It's not about not wanting this, it's about if this is technically solvable without bogging down the server by millions of outstanding transactions.

Comment: I tried to show it as a tradeoff, i.e. essentially a "prediction" of what would happen based on the local data that gets sent to the `Stream` immediately and then the real update coming in from the server later. This means that an issue on GitHub would be not worth anything because I am clearly missing the point and should handle it on my own?

Comment: Transactions are about hard guarantees, there is not much room for tradeoffs. They are also very expensive for the server and Firebase is all about scaleability where transactions are a tradeoff already.

Comment: As mentioned, Google has smart people and my knowledge is limited. Perhaps they found a smart way to handle this but just Flutter does not implement it. If it works on Android native or if the docs explain it the way you want it, it's definitely worth an issue.

Comment: I was wrong about the Android part, as I found out after researching it. I never doubted the ability of anyone working on the project. I was just wondering as the project is relatively new. I understand the ACID part and as I feel like it would not be worth bothering other people with making something that works in every scenario, I will just continue implementing it myself. I was just thinking about an optional paramater.

Answer (score 2):

Transactions cannot be instantaneous.  They will always require a round trip with the server in order to ensure a truly correct and atomic update.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and obviously they cannot. I did not even expect this. I wanted to know if there was a way to push an update to the `Stream` that is handled locally in exactly the same way it happens with `updateData` as demonstrated in the video. I know that this update might be faulty, that is what I am doing on my own as well, until the server pushes the new value.