# How do I know if a transaction on Firestore succeded?

Tags: flutter, dart, transactions, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any method to know if the transaction was successful? I need to implement a loading "widget animation" if I upload large archives and spend too much time on that. And then change the screen after success, but I don't know-how.

Thanks!

Transaction Example:

```
CollectionReference reference = Firestore.instance.collection("collection_example");

Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction transaction) async {

await transaction.set(reference, {
  "index_1":"ABC",
  "index_2": 2,
  "index_3": {"mapIndex_1": "ABC"}
});

});
```

Comment: Does runTransaction return a future that you can await?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot receive that from your [`runTransaction`](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/lib/src/firestore.dart#L107) call in this case because it returns a `Future<Map<String, dynamic>>`. As *I have **checked***, it will always return an **empty** `Map`. Thus there is nothing to get from the `runTransaction` function itself.

You can easily get a `Stream` of updates from your reference though, which would look something like this:

```
DocumentReference documentReference;

firestore.runTransaction( // firestore in this case is your Firestore instance
  (Transaction transaction) async {
    // whatever you do here with your reference
    await transaction.update(
      documentReference,
      ...
);

documentReference.snapshots().listen((DocumentSnapshot event) {
  // here you could e.g. check if the transaction on your reference was succesful
});
```

As you can see I used the `snapshots()` `Stream<DocumentSnapshot)` on the *same* `DocumentReference` as the *transaction* was run on. The `Stream` will update *as soon as the transaction has completed* and the server reached back to you.

*To see why* transaction results cannot be evaluated client-side check the [answers on my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50707300/6509751).

Comment: I faced a very similar problem and publishing a result obtained during the execution of a transaction handler on a stream was the only way to get it out.